# What version of GLSL does WebGL use

Tags: glsl, webgl

Is this a per device sort of thing? Or is it based on the browser? Sorry for such a basic question but I cant seem to find a straight answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shaders in WebGL vs openGL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364213/shaders-in-webgl-vs-opengl)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, and according to [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#4.3), it must support GLSL **ES** version [1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf). In fact that is [all it supports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105201/868679).

On another note, this has been my general reference for GLSL features: http://www.shaderific.com/glsl/

Comment: Another good reference for WebGL is [the official Khronos WebGL Cheat Sheet](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf).

Comment: A great answer by @gman here "Shaders in WebGL vs openGL? "http://stackoverflow.com/q/30364213/3291506